# If X~G(0,01): What is the probability that: The first success is the fortieth trial? The first twelve trials will fail?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### Exercise

> An automatic machine manufactures microcircuits one at a time and
>   independently. Each microcircuit has a probability of $0, 01$ being
>   defective.
>
> a) Calculate the probability that the first defective microcircuit in
>   a working day is the fortieth that is made.
>
> b) Probability that the first twelve microcircuits manufactured are
>   all correct.

### Solution

Let X: "Number of circuits diagnosed as correct, before diagnosing the first circuit as defective",

then $X$~$G(0.01)$, so $f_X(x)=0.99^x*0.01$

- a) $f_X(39) = 0.00675729...$
- b) $f_X(12) = 0.008863848...$

**Is my solution correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Okay.  $f_X(39)$ is the probability that the first defective circuit is the fortieth circuit.

b) Rethink this one.  $f_X(12)$ is the probability that the first defective circuit is exactly the thirteenth circuit.   You want $1-F_X(12)$ the probability that the first defective circuit made is *at least* the thirteenth. Where $F_X(x)$ is the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF).

Comment: Sorry for so many editions and comments deleted, I do not know what is happening. But thank you very much for the answer.